# What is this bird?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I have found this bird in my house, I live in Haedo, Buenos Aires, Argentina. I tried to take a closer photo but it escaped flying. I am not sure how to describe it, but it's very big compared to normal birds.

This are the photos:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That specimen in your photo seems to be the [Southern Crested Caracara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_crested_caracara), *Caracara plancus*:

[image]

Also your location matches the range of *C. plancus*, which is from northern Brazil to Tierra del Fuego:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the US , I would say it could be an osprey , especially if there is a body of water nearby. Or Caracas if in dry grasslands.